# Swift, Xcode: How to copy a random file to the root of the application during the build

Tags: swift, xcode

Maybe a silly question and the answer is obvious but I could not find any relevant information so far.
I moved from Visual Studio environment to Xcode and Swift. I need to copy a file ( in my case application.json to the root of the application during the build. This is very trivial in Microsoft World.
With Xcode I can declare a resource in Package.swift  which is copied to the target bundle. However I need it in the root of the application, not in the bundle. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What is "the root of the application, not in the bundle?" Everything in an application is in its bundle. (I suspect what you're asking for is impossible with Swift Package Manager. SPM does not permit arbitrary actions in the build, and cannot handle a wide variety of common build steps; it's a very new and limited tool. With a traditional Xcode build, you'd do this a Copy Files step, or at worst a Run Script step in the build. But it's not clear where you're trying to put this file.)

Comment: I am just trying to copy  application.json file in the root ( on the same level as the executable) folder as some library expects it there. That is very common and trivial in many other frameworks but I could not figure out how to do it with swift package manager.

Comment: "SPM does not permit arbitrary actions in the build, and cannot handle a wide variety of common build steps; it's a very new and limited tool." There is no way to move files to arbitrary locations in the package today.